# What are the benefits of applying Apache Tika to Solr instead of Nutch

Tags: solr, nutch, apache-tika

I am trying to crawl data with Apache Nutch and index it with Apache Solr.

As part of this I want to parse the content as well. I am trying to figure out is it better to apply Tika to Nutch  , to Solr or both.

Answer (score 2):

Apply it as early as you can but make sure to keep the original, full-fidelity, document somewhere as well.

There is no point passing a binary file around if you know that in the end you are going to reduce it to a set of metadata fields and get rid of the rest.